# Travelling Salesman C Program Error

Tags: c

Am writing a programme to solve TSP for n towns(towns and shortest route to cover them all). The approach is to ask the user for the coordinates of towns and then the programme should calculate the distance using the equation for distance between two points on the plain:
d=((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)^1/2;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void check(int);
int distance(int, int, int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    int n;
    int i; //number of towns
    int coord[12][3];
    int dist[12][12];
    printf("how many towns?\n");//should be more than 1 and no more than 12 to be handled by the compiler
    scanf("%d", &n);
    check(n);
    printf("for the plain 10x10 give town coordinates\n\n");//e.g. 1(0,4), 2(3,7)
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        coord[i][0]=i+1;//town number
        printf("town %d\n", i+1);
        printf("x=\n");
        scanf("%d", &coord[i][1]);//first coordinate
        printf("y=\n");
        scanf("%d", &coord[i][2]);//second coordinate
        printf("\n");
    }

    distance(n, coord, dist);                
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}

void check(int n)
{
    if(n<=1)
    printf("wrong number; start over\n");
    return;
}

int distance(int n, int coord[][], int dist[][])
{
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            dist[i][j]=sqrt(pow((coord[i][1]-coord[j][1]), 2)- pow((coord[i][2]-coord[j][2]), 2));
            printf("%d\n", dist[i][j];
        }
    } 
}
```

The program is only partially done and I wanted to test whether the programme can print the distance between each town. However I get this error:
"passing arg 2 'distance' makes integer from pointer without cast"
I am aware that dist should return flow, but I was testing different formats as well changing number of variables in 'distance' function.

Comment: Take a look at the `distance` prototype declaration right above `main`. Compare it to the actual `distance` definition.

Comment: If you straight copied your code,  `printf("%d\n", dist[i][j];` in `distance` has a missing close-paren

Comment: I corrected the bracket but it still crashes with the same error, also cannot find fault with prototype distance

Answer (score 2):

The prototype is for a function taking three single integers as arguments, not one integer and two matrices.

And you can't define the function like that if you have matrices (arrays of arrays), then you need to either specify the size of the innermost "dimension":

```
int distance(int n, int coord[][3], int dist[][12]);
```

*Or* declare them as a pointer to arrays:

```
int distance(int n, int (*coord)[], int (*dist)[]);
```

Comment: If this answer was useful to you, please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). For more information see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) at Stack Overflow Meta.